# seaborn count plot each line to represent total count and non zero count

Tags: python, plot, count, seaborn

i would like to plot a seaborn count plot per below :

```
    df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Class' : [1,1, 2 ,2, 2, 3, 3,3], 'check' : [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]})
df3
```

> ```
>   Class check
> 0 1   0
> 1 1   1
> 2 2   0
> 3 2   1
> 4 2   0
> 5 3   1
> 6 3   0
> 7 3   1
> ```

```
sns.countplot(data =df3, y = 'Class', hue = 'check', orient = 'v')
```

I would like to get the result like this but :

- the blue line to represent all counts not 0s only, so the first blue line would have count of 2, the 2nd blue line count of 3...
- Or even more ideal would be instead of 2 lines per row to have only 1 line, with total value (count of 0s and 1s) and count of 1s on it.

From this,

[image]
to This:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
 pd.crosstab(df3['Class'], df3['check']).plot.barh(stacked=True)
```

Output:

[image]

---

```
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
ax = pd.crosstab(df3['Class'], df3['check']).plot.barh(stacked=True)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MultipleLocator(1))
_ = ax.set_xlabel('Count')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thank you, how to change the chart size? as mine has many labels on the y axis. plt.figure(figzise=(x,y)) doesn't work.

Comment: add `figsize=(10,8)` inside barh method... `ax = pd.crosstab(df3['Class'], df3['check']).plot.barh(stacked=True, figsize=(10,8))`